# rhub : How can I force the installation of data.table in rhub?

Tags: r, data.table, cran

I have this error in Rhub :

Package required but not available: 'data.table'

How can I fix it ? Must I use Rtools to compile data.table ? How can I send to rhub the source of data.table ?

```
> check_for_cran()

─  Building package
─  Uploading package
─  Preparing build, see status at
   http://builder.r-hub.io/status/antaresRead_2.1.0.tar.gz-ce77306bf5ed4e209d7ab47e29cb8e1d
   http://builder.r-hub.io/status/antaresRead_2.1.0.tar.gz-a55c7a25f1194d1099b8caff38ac75ad
   http://builder.r-hub.io/status/antaresRead_2.1.0.tar.gz-ab116b954ad74365b38ea9e351865755
─  Build started
─  Creating new user
─  Downloading and unpacking package file
─  Querying package dependencies
─  Installing package dependencies
─  Running R CMD check
   setting _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_ to false
   setting _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_ to true
   setting _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_USE_ASPELL_ to true
─  using log directory 'C:/Users/USERjsUieVILNr/antaresRead.Rcheck'
─  using R Under development (unstable) (2018-02-19 r74276)
─  using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
─  using session charset: ISO8859-1
─  using option '--as-cran'
✔  checking for file 'antaresRead/DESCRIPTION'
─  checking extension type ... Package
─  this is package 'antaresRead' version '2.1.0'
─  package encoding: UTF-8
N  checking CRAN incoming feasibility
> 
> 
> New submission


   Maintainer: 'Jalal-Edine ZAWAM <jalal-edine.zawam@rte-france.com>'
   Package was archived on CRAN

   Possibly mis-spelled words in DESCRIPTION:
     R�seau (16:41)
     de (16:48)
     d� (16:61)
     lectricit� (16:64)

   CRAN repository db overrides:
     X-CRAN-Comment: Archived on 2018-02-20 as check problems were not
       corrected despite reminders.

     Unconditional use of Suggests package(s) from BioC.
✔  checking package namespace information
E  checking package dependencies
   Package required but not available: 'data.table'

   See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
   manual.

── 1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 1 note ✖
─  Done with R CMD check
─  Cleaning up files and user
```

How to prevent this error  Package required but not available: 'data.table' ?

Comment: That seems like a bug. Your [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/rte-antares-rpackage/antaresRead/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) has the `Imports` (in master and branches), and `NAMESPACE` looks right too.  Maybe file an [issue here](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub/issues) (as I don't know a better place) ?

Comment: data.table is not available on CRAN for R-devel as a binary package. Instead of R-devel windows, you could just try R-release windows, and check R-devel on Linux.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel for your advise, I added a comment in an issue [here](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub/issues/123), I think a lot of people have the same issue with rhub. And thanks GaborCsardi for your advice, yes the package data.table is not available for R-devel on CRAN but building the package is OK. There is some errors in test. Maybe, the user can tell to rhub to install data.table from source and not from binary ?

Comment: No, Gabor said that on r-devel for Windows, it is not available.  And there is usually a reason so I would not assume you can install it locally. Follow Gabor's advice: r-release on Windows, r-devel on Linux.  That way you still get r-devel.